# Find Picard exceptional values

Tags: complex-analysis

I have a problem with the following task. I need to find (if there are) picard’s exceptional values of the function $z^8+\sin ^2(3z)+e^{z^2}$ point $\infty$ of entire function is not exceptional value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(z) = z^8 + \sin(3z)^2 + e^{z^2}$ be the function at hand.

Since $f(\mathbb{R}) \subset \mathbb{R}$, it satisfies
$\overline{f(z)} = f(\bar{z})$. A consequence of this is if $f(z)$ avoids any $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$, it need to avoid $\bar{\alpha}$ too. Since $f(z)$ can avoid at most one number, this forces $\alpha = \bar{\alpha}$ and $\alpha$ need to be real.

It is not hard to see $f(\mathbb{R}) = [1,\infty)$ and $f(i\mathbb{R}) = (-\infty,1]$. This means $f(z)$ doesn't avoid any real number. As a result,$f(z)$ doesn't avoid any complex number.

Comment: What about point zero? I think that there is no point on $i \mathbb{R}$ for which $f$ is equal to zero

Comment: So for $f(\mathbb{R}) \subset \mathbb{R}$ it is easy to show. I have a problem with the second one

Comment: Notice $f(iy) = y^8 - \sinh(3y)^2 + e^{-y^2}$. We have $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) \to \infty$ and $\lim_{y\to\infty} f(iy) = -\infty$. Since $f(0) = 1$ and $f(x), f(iy)$ are continuous, IVT tell us $f(\mathbb{R}) \supset [1,\infty)$ and $f(i\mathbb{R}) \supset (-\infty,1])$. They are actually equal but this is strong enough to deduce $f(\mathbb{R}) \cup f(i\mathbb{R}) = \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: So why intermediate value theorem formally holds for complex case? In my course there wasn’t such proposition , so I wondering why is this true. Of course we can represent our function as sum of two real-valued functions for which theorem holds

Comment: Along the real and/or imaginary axis, $f(z)$ is real and you can apply IVT there.

Comment: Oh, I forgot about the generalization of IVT